# Where is the Coverage tab in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[Find unused JavaScript and CSS code with the Coverage tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/coverage/#open-the-coverage-tool), but don't know where to open the Coverage tab

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Coverage tool

1. Open the Command Menu.
   Click the Customize and control DevTools(...) menu button, and then select Run command:
   Or, press Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows, Linux) or Command+Shift+P (macOS).
2. Start typing coverage, select the Show Coverage command, and then press Enter. The Coverage tool opens in the Drawer.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, and most probably in all Chromium based browsers, the Coverage section can be enabled like on the image.

[image: Coverage in Chrome]

Comment: Please add precise steps from when you open chrome!

Comment: @Adelin just click on the 3 vertical dots in the inspector top right corner, and you'll get the menu as in the screenshot!